# order of deleting rows in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have this code which should work

```
delete from
(
select oi.* from orderinfo oi
where oi.order_status = 'Выполнен'
and
oi.rowid in
(
select orderinfo.rowid from orderinfo
inner join ordered_medicines om on oi.order_id = om.order_id and oi.order_status = 'Выполнен'
inner join medicine_instances mi on om.medicine_id_instance = mi.medicine_id_instance
));
```

but the problem is that due to primary keys i cannot start deleting from orderInfo (ORA-02292), i should delete 1st in oredered_medicines and only then from orderinfo, i have tried this:

```
Delete from (
select om.* from ordered_medicines om
where oi.order_id = 'Выполнен'
and
om.rowid in (
select ordered_medicines.rowid from ordered_medicines
inner join orderinfo oi on oi.order_id = om.order_id
)
);
```

but it doesnt work, i think because oi. is not defined yet.
so what way i can delete first from ordered_medicines base on orderInfow cell`s status, on only then from irderinfo?

Comment: I suspect you should be using cascading delete foreign key references instead -- so the database does such deletes automatically.

Comment: But i can not add ON DELETE CASCADE to an already existing constraint

Comment: Drop it, then create it using ON DELETE CASCADE.